# How text is displayed in android?

Tags: android, text

I am developing an android application. Could anybody tell me or send any link about how text is displayed in android. As far as images is concerned, we can specify the size in dp to keep the size constant. How to do this for android so that it remains readable across devices?

Answer (score 2):

You specify your text sizes using the SP unit.

> Similarly, you should prefer the sp (scale-independent pixel) to
>   define text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and
>   the system scales the size the same as it does for dp.

Refer to Android Docs on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: what size is chosen if `wrap_content` is used ?

Comment: sp is only used font-size. If you use wrap_content on a TextView, the TextView will only be as big as the text, who's font size you set in units of SP

Comment: but if I do not set any font size , what will be the default

Comment: also, what is the recommended sp , so that text is readable

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOrderProduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:onClick="hideKeyBord"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:width="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextOrderQty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:width="50dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextOrderprice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:width="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOrderStock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:onClick="hideKeyBord"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:width="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```